# Extend IIS FTP to limit allowed file types by folder

Tags: iis-7, ftp

I need to restrict FTP uploads to specific file extensions. Each folder under a user's home directory will allow different file types. For example:

/Design - will only allow .psd, .pdf, .jpg
/Data - will only allow .txt, .csv, and .xls

(These folders point to different servers, which seems easy enough.)

I see how I can extend FTP with DLLs for authentication, but not for uploading files.

Is there a way to do this? Or does anyone know of another FTP server that would allow this - either through built in settings, plugins, extensions?

Comment: Request filtering also helps prevent access to extensions, http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.ftpServer/security/requestFiltering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [File Server Resource Manager](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2008/08/20/the-basics-of-windows-server-2008-fsrm-file-server-resource-manager.aspx) which can be installed with the File and Print Services role to manage what extensions are allowed in what directories. As far as I'm aware, there's no IIS-native way to do this, but FSRM is clean and easy and can also put quotas, email usage, and other useful things on the folders in question.